# R: overlay multiple plots with same y axis ggplot2 (with datapoints and only geom_smooth lines)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Maybe someone knows a simple solution to this:

I have a R script that produces several plots with ggplot2 out of one dataframe. These plots on their own look somewhat like these 2 images:
[image][image]

The problem I have: This script generates about 20 plots, all are using different variables and values for the x-axies, and the same variable but different values for the y-axies.

In general the plots look like this:

```
plot.a <- ggplot(DF[which(DF$a>0&DF$a<200),], aes(x=a, y=myY))+
    geom_point(shape=1, color=color2, alpha=alpha) +  
    labs(title='a vs y', x='a', y='y')+
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, color = color)+ ..

plot.b <- ggplot(DF[which(DF$b>0),], aes(x=b, y=myY))+
    geom_point(shape=1, color=color2, alpha=alpha) +  
    labs(title='b vs. y', x='b', y='y')+
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, color = color)+ ..
```

As you can see the different plots use different columns of the same DF and also only relevant data (e.g. DF$b>0 on plot.b but on plot.a DF$a<200) so there are not all lines of data used in every plot.

Now I want to combine all these plots (about 20 plots) into one plot with the same y-axies but different x-axies. I'am mainly interested in the **geom_smooth** trend lines of all plots.

Is there a way to combine all these plots into a new ggplot (or only the geom_smooth lines), with the same y-axies and adding and displaying for every new smooth line a new x-axies?

For better reading of the new plot, is it possible to create a different color of every geom_smooth and the corresponding x-axies (e.g. color = plottype) with a legend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a new column where you filter the data you want to plot. Then you can `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid(..., scales = "free_x")` for separate plots with the same y-axis.  For all data on the same plot, forgo the facet and define colors & groups by your new column.

Comment: My DF columns looks like this: `Date, a, b, c, ...` so for every date I have a set of a, b, c,..
How to create a new column with this, when I need values from multiple columns? The y-axis should always be 'date' and then the differen x-axes should represent 'a', 'b',... Thanks!

Comment: Use `gather` in `tidyr` to go from you "wide" data (Date, a, b, c, ...) to "long" data (Date, value, letter). Then filter out the rows you don't want. Then plot with `facet_grid`.

Comment: Ok thanks, got this! How can I filter the data for the "plot data"? In the ggplot data input?